# Power Query: Table.Group with a dynamic list of columns specifying column type

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have
`ttOKLostTypes=Table.Group(#"Pivoted Column", {"Index"}, List.Transform(columnList2, each {_, (grp) => List.Max(Table.Column(grp, _)) })),`
However this resets column types. How can I specify column types in the above transformation as here:

```
 #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Pivoted Column", {"Index"}, {{"InvoiceDate", each List.Max([InvoiceDate]),type nullable date},....
```

I know I can find out column types by using

```
schema=Table.Schema(#"Pivoted Column"),
```

but I cannot figure out how can I build a proper List with column types to be used in the Table.Group()

Answer (score 1):

You can build a dynamic list of all the aggregations to include the data type, using `List.Transform`, by just adding the data type to your transformation.

Assuming the data types are all the same:

For example, if your grouping column is "Column1", then

```
   maxCols = List.RemoveItems(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),{"Column1"}),
    colAggregations = 
        List.Transform(
            maxCols,
                (c)=> {c, each List.Max(Table.Column(_,c)),Int64.Type}
            ),

    group = Table.Group(#"Changed Type","Column1", colAggregations)
```

***EDIT***

To include the types of the original columns, dynamically, is more difficult.  `Table.Schema` will return the column types **as text** so they have to be transformed into a `Type`.

One way to do this is with a custom function.

**Custom Function**
***name it:  `fnTextToType`***
*I only included a few types. The Field name is a name returned by Table.Schema for a particular type, and the field value is the type. It is hopefully obvious how to extend this function to account for other types*

```
(txt as text) =>
let 
   typeRecord = 
    Record.Field(
        [Number.Type = Number.Type,
         Int64.Type = Int64.Type,
         DateTime.Type = DateTime.Type],
        txt
    ) 
in 
    typeRecord
```

Then you can use it in code like this:

```
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(rem,{{"Column1", Int64.Type}, {"Column2", type number}, {"Column3", Int64.Type}}),

//get list of column types in column order
//note these are returned as text strings and not as "types"
    colTypes =  Table.Schema(#"Changed Type")[TypeName],

//create list of columns upon which to execute the aggregation (List.Max in this case)
    maxCols = List.RemoveItems(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),{"Column1"}),

//create list of aggregations
    colAggregations = 
        List.Transform(maxCols,(c)=> {c, each List.Max(Table.Column(_,c)),
        fnTextToType(colTypes{List.PositionOf(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),c)})}),
        
//now group them
    group = Table.Group(#"Changed Type","Column1", colAggregations)
in
    group
```

You can see how the types were maintained in the screenshots below.

**Changed Type**
[image]

**group**
[image]

Comment: This does not work. I have a number of columns of different type, not just one type as in your example.

Comment: @AnonymousExplorer That's more difficult but doable. I'll post something probably later this evening.

Comment: @AnonymousExplorer  Please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ron Rosenfeld. Your answer which works suggested me to find another way using Expression.Evaluate. Evaluate without #shared does not work. See https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2015/02/06/expression-evaluate-in-power-querym/

```
columnList = Table.ColumnNames(#"Pivoted Column"),
columnList2 = List.RemoveItems(columnList,{"Index"}),
ColListWithTypes = List.Transform(columnList2,(colName)=> {colName,Table.SelectRows(schema,each [Name]=colName)[TypeName]{0}}),    
ttTestWithTypes=Table.Group(#"Pivoted Column", {"Index"}, List.Transform(ColListWithTypes, each {_{0}, (grp) => List.Max(Table.Column(grp, _{0})),Expression.Evaluate(_{1},#shared)})),
```